# dynamically generate css content not taking effect

Tags: python, css, django

I need to generate css based on client queries.  I use the @import url() directive inside some style tags to call a method to produce a text string response of css.  I can see the css is generated correctly in firebug, but it doesn't take effect.

If I serve the exact same css from my site media directory use the @import directive everything works fine.

my html header code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url("{{ css_url }}")
/*@import url("/site_media/css/style.css")*/
</style>
```

my django python code:

```
string = u'#exampleTextInput{ background-color:#ff0000;}\n'
return HttpResponse(string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set a Content-Type response header; that'd be my first guess:

```
string = u'#exampleTextInput{ background-color:#ff0000;}\n'
return HttpResponse(string, content_type='text/css')
```